# Disabling dropdown options if already selected

Tags: c#, .net, drop-down-menu

I have a site where people can upload images into a sort of "image mosiac".  They can select from a drop down of 36 different positions.  Is there a way to disable certain selections from the dropdown if it has already been selected.  I don't care if it is grayed out, removed, disabled, or simply having an error message in the error label (which is already there and functioning) saying "please select a different location" (or whatever I decide later).

I just don't want people to select a duplicate location and have the app submit the video.  What kind of checking can I put in this?

```
protected void PopulateImagePosition()
{
    String[] imagePositions = video.ListImagePositions();

    image_position.Items.Add(new ListItem("----- Please Select -----", ""));
    foreach (String tmpPosition in imagePositions)
    {
        String[] parts = tmpPosition.Split(new char[] { '|' });

        image_position.Items.Add(new ListItem(parts[1], parts[0]));
    }
}
```

This is C# .NET.  If I need to have additional; code please let me know, any help would be appreciated.  Thank in advance!

Comment: The best would be to remove this option from the DropDownList. Where do you store the selection, in a rdbms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got to try stating the obvious

```
foreach (String tmpPosition in imagePositions)
{
    // add logic here to skip if imagePosition has already been selected 
    // or just don't include it in imagePositions if it has already been selected
    String[] parts = tmpPosition.Split(new char[] { '|' });
    image_position.Items.Add(new ListItem(parts[1], parts[0]));
}
```